# That new top bar that no one ever talks about

Tags: discussion, top-bar

I know there are plans to roll this out to *other* sites on the network - but does that include chat.stackoverflow.com as a subdomain? It's on main and meta, but chat seems to have been left all alone and as a regular user of chat it's starting to irk me.

That's right, irk.

I assume it will, but I've not seen anything explicitly mention chat. If someone can confirm or deny this I'll tell Schrödinger to put his cat away and I'll get back to sleeping well at night.

Kthxbai.

Comment: Not exactly the new topbar but if you like a top bar all the way in chat you might like this userscript: https://stackapps.com/questions/7404/top-bar-for-chat-rooms

Comment: Cheers rene, that's a nice hack - it's more the layout of the icons being on opposite sides tbh. I might make a userscript myself if it's going to be a long wait.

Comment: Is assume this is about the new [top-bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/top-bar/info), not about the [new-nav](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/new-nav/info)?

Comment: @Floern yes, I shall edit as appropriate

Comment: That…isn't how Schrödinger's cat works.

Comment: It was the whole "it's neither confirmed nor denied" thing - it was a stretch admittedly, made more sense in my head (as most things do)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> does that include chat.stackoverflow.com as a subdomain?

Yes, eventually.

It has already been rolled out to the international Stack Overflow sites and we are working on rolling it out to the remaining Q&A sites, though that's expected to take a while.

Once those are done, we will be updating (in no particular order) chat, area 51, se.com and any other properties that have the "old" one.

Comment: Cheers Oded - I can sleep better now. Once you have a date though I do expect an SO calendar with a nice freehand red circle around that date so I can mark each day off in anticipation.

Comment: [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/140505) is the best I can do here, @MacroMan

Comment: touché Oded, touché...

Comment: "Once those are done, we will be updating... area 51['s top bar]" Yay! Finally an excuse for updating A51's codebase!

Comment: @Oded Has any non-SO site gotten the new top bar yet?

Comment: Not yet, @Michael - there's work in progress to get it there (delayed for various reasons).